# How to repair B1C2B error code for Dodge Grand Caravan 2013?

Tags: dodge, grand-caravan

It will be higly appreciated if someone can help in trouble shooting the error code B1C2B in my 2013 Dodge Grand Caravan. It has a 3.6L Engine. I know little about cars. Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the second part of the code? it should have a hyphen and a number after the B1C2B code e.g. B1C2B-11

Answer (score 1):

It appears this diagnostic code is for the front passenger airbag. It is important that you resolve this issue as soon as possible, as any fault with the airbag system will shut off all airbag function, rendering them useless in the event of a crash until the issue is fixed.

A couple forums have said they were able to resolve this specific issue by removing the glove box to gain access the passenger airbag, and using MAF or electronic safe cleaning spray (available in the automotive section at most department stores) on the contacts that give that airbag power.

If you are not comfortable doing this yourself following the rudimentary procedure [here](http://forum.chryslerminivan.net/showthread.php/18856-Passenger-Squib-Circuit-Open), take the car to a **trusted** mechanic and ask them to check and clean the contacts for the passenger airbag. If they try to tell you there are additional problems, **get a second opinion** before committing to a expensive airbag replacement. A corroded contact is likely the only problem, but you never know until you look.

Good luck!

Comment: I think B1C2B refers to the passenger in seat airbag and not the dash airbag in this case.